# Recibo null siempre al deserializar un json con array de objetos

Tags: c#, json, deserialize

No sé que estoy haciendo mal, tengo un Json extremadamente sencillo, pero no consigo deserializarlo, es que ya no sé que más probar.
el JSON es este:

```
{"value":[{"Id":"2b0af0d7-2a7b-4489-a205-8cb9aef88a1b","Code":"1","Name":"Empresa Pripal"},{"Id":"39e415d3-d971-404a-b5ca-fc7f039dd859","Code":"3","Name":"Empresa 3 "},{"Id":"b8405286-a3d1-4d40-9a64-ec8fde498342","Code":"75","Name":"Empresa pruevas"},{"Id":"ec624692-5383-44a8-822a-3493ff177c02","Code":"99","Name":"Empresa 99"}]}
```

la entidad es:

```
public class Empresas
{
    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    IEnumerable<Empresa> value { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Y intento deserializar el Json tal que así:

```
Empresas tryObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Empresas>(data);
```

Pero tryObject siempre vale null.
Es obvio que algo estoy haciendo mal, podéis ayudarme por favor.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba a marcar ambas clases con [`[Serializable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente es porque la propiedad "value" de Empresa debe ser "public", intenta  cambiando esto

Mira un ejemplo online con tu mismo codigo, pero compile y que se ejecuta correctamente

- [Deserialize JSON with object array](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JJOyvL)
  https://dotnetfiddle.net/JJOyvL

Quedaria el codigo asi

```
public class Empresas
{
    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public IEnumerable<Empresa> value { get; set; }
}

public class Empresa
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recomendacion, puedes cambiar el nombre de la propiedad "value" para no utilizar [una palabra reservada de C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/), pero ademas para que quede mas semantico la clase y no como esta en el JSON (por eso nos ayudamos con el atributo del nombre)
Algo asi

```
public class EmpresasWrapper
{
    [JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public IEnumerable<Empresa> Empresas { get; set; }
}
```

Idem para la parte de Empresa. Para que no tengas Id, Name (sino como tu lo diseñes y te ayudas con el nombre del campo de JSON con el atributo JsonPropertyName)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: Cierto, era el modificador de la propiedad, al establecerlo a public se solucionó.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Estás tratando de deserializar una lista de objetos como un objeto sencillo. Intenta envolver tu model en una lista. prueba esto:

`List<Empresas> = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Empresas>>(data);`

Otra cosa, pon un punto de interrupción en el momento en que haces el deserializa y checa si data trae algo antes de ejecutar el deserialize.
Pudiera ser que estes mapeando mal la property. Si puedes agrega screenshot de eso porfa.

Comment: Si te fijas, el objeto Empresa, es el que contiene el IEnumerable para "alojar" el array de objetos.
Si que trae data ya que lo he reducido todo al absurdo en un proyecto para consola para ver donde está el error, y no hay manera

Comment: Y duda, ese JSON lo estás recuperando de una llamada http o lo estás mapeando a mano?
Sí lo recuperas de un response por fa, pon el código de como haces el llamado y que response te da.